# Почему конструктор выполняется бесконечное количество раз

Tags: c#

Написал класс Valera, затем в конструкторе класса заполнил поля, считанные с json файла. Но программа не работает, так как конструктор выполняется бесконечное количество раз и вызывает пере. В чем ошибка? Выполняется бесконечное количество раз ReadAllText.

```
public class Valera
    {
        public int health {get; set;} // Здоровье 0-100
        public int mana {get; set;} // Мана 0-100
        public int happiness {get; set;} // Жизнерадостность (-10; 10)
        public int fatigue {get; set;} // Усталость 0-100
        public bool dead {get; set;} // Состояние Валеры
    
    public Valera()
    {
        var jsonObject =
            File.ReadAllText(
                @"C:\Users\User\RiderProjects\MarginalValera\MarginalValera\Properties\characteristics.json");
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Valera>(jsonObject);

        health = obj.health;
        mana = obj.mana;
        happiness = obj.happiness;
        fatigue = obj.fatigue;
        dead = obj.dead;
    }
```

Вызов конструктора:

```
internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Valera valera = new Valera();
            //valera.init();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Для десериализации, десериализатор создаёт экземпляр класса, который заполняет данными.... А при созданиии, есессно вызывается конструктор ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: а зачем  десериализовать в этот же класс? В этом случае и конструктор не нужен, десериализатор сам разложит по полям

Answer (score 1):

Нужно вынести десериализацию из конструктора, иначе получается рекурсия.

Valera.cs:

```
public class Valera
{
    public int health {get; set;} // Здоровье 0-100
    public int mana {get; set;} // Мана 0-100
    public int happiness {get; set;} // Жизнерадостность (-10; 10)
    public int fatigue {get; set;} // Усталость 0-100
    public bool dead {get; set;} // Состояние Валеры
}
```

Program.cs:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\User\RiderProjects\MarginalValera\MarginalValera\Properties\characteristics.json");
var valera = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Valera>(json);
```